# Xamarin.forms android listviewrenderer

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to use a onscroll-listener for listview, as far i know this isn't buildin in xamarin.forms.ListView.
So using a renderer is logic solution till I saw Xamarin.Forms.Android doesn't have a ListViewRenderer yet.. IOS does,

What are the alternatives? How can I implement a scroll listener or get the first visible view in a other way? 
Thnx! ,

Comment: comeon, anyone knows this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is ListViewRenderer but unfortunately it is internal. You might consider subclassing ListView and create your own ViewRenderer based renderer.
But that might be a lot of work. Ask in the Xamarin forums and/or create uservoice request...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I did ask on forums.xamarin, I did get as answer that for my needs itemsDissapearing will fit, But I need to know only items which are on top are dissapearing. Not from the bottom. Is there a check for that? So only if the user scrolls down and a item dissapears it should listen to it,